# Parsing data retrieved from registerForActivityResult via background service

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm trying to build a camera application using ZXing library, everything is up and running (overlay is displaying on the screen while the application is minimized)

My problem is - activity result only gets called once the application is back from minimized state. How could I get the data without bringing back the app from minimized state? As far as I know calling registerForActivityResult from a service is not possible.

I have a background service already running, which could be *somehow* used to parse the data

Comment: What is a minimized state?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Home button is pressed, so the application is running in the background